# Standardized free survey besides SUS

Tags: tools

Do you know of any standardized surveys freely available such as the System Usability Scale (SUS)? If it is only free for academic purpuses it's also good (I want to use it during a practical course at the university). Published data would be also nice for the sake of comparison (well, if it's standardized, it should have some data published somewhere...).

Answer (score 6):

In the book *Measuring the User Experience* by Tullis and Albert, there's a section which mentions a study that compares post-session self-reported metrics:

> Tullis and Stetson (2004) reported a study that compared a variety of post-session questionnaires for measuring user reactions to websites in an online usability study.

SUS apparently scored highest in that comparison study. The other methods listed are:

- QUIS
- CSUQ
- Words
- Study's

I don't really know much about those others, but I'm sure you could find out about them with a bit of searching.

Answer (score 6):

There's a [great article about SUS](http://www.humanfactors.com/downloads/jan10.asp#research) over at HFI (via UsabilityNews) that I've just read.  Well worth a read.

Comment: My team has questioned the validity of a SUS lately because they feel the questions don't relate directly to a web experience. Survey takers also laugh or get confused by some of the questions.

Thanks for sending this article though to reinforce the value! I am going to a post a question on UXExchange to see if others encounter the lack of respect for SUS in their shops.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for alternative usability surveys, you should try Gary Perlman's [User Interface Usability Evaluation with Web-Based Questionnaires](http://oldwww.acm.org/perlman/question.html). This is a web site that allows you to set up and administer the following usability surveys:

- Questionnaire for User Interface
  Satisfaction
- Perceived Usefulness and Ease of Use
- Nielsen's Attributes of Usability
- Nielsen's Heuristic Evaluation
- Computer System Usability
  Questionnaire
- After Scenario Questionnaire
- Practical Heuristics for Usability
  Evaluation
- Purdue Usability Testing
  Questionnaire
- USE Questionnaire

However, because the SUS survey has such good comparative data, it's really worth persevering with it if you can.